# Button click resets a web page

Tags: javascript, dom, event-delegation

A web page resets as soon as I click button that makes a simple alert.
The problem occurs only when clicking a button that isn't in the DOM from the beginning.

```js
function addNewBook (book, author, pages) {
    // Add inputs and labels to the HTML form
    document.getElementById('book-form').innerHTML = 
    `<label for="book">Name</label><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <label for="author">Author</label><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <label for="pages">Pages</label><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <div id="button-div">
        <button id="submit-button">SUBMIT</button>
    </div>`
}

// Adding eventlistener to already-existing button that
// triggers the creation of the next button
document.getElementById("new-book-button").addEventListener("click", function () {
    addNewBook("goodName", "goodAuthor", "540")
});

// When this button is clicked, the webpage is reset, 
// the book + form created by the addNewBook function are removed.
// Event delegation used since button is not in the DOM from the beginning.
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.matches('#submit-button')) {
        alert('hi')
    }
});
```

How do I get around this issue so that I can simply collapse the form and allow for the user to add another book by making the form popup again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply add event.preventDefault();

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.matches('#submit-button')) {
event.preventDefault();
        alert('hi')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For most browsers the default type of button is submit. Add [type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button) property to button, which can be programmed to control custom functionality when assigned an event handler function (typically for the click event).

```
<button type="button" id="submit-button">SUBMIT</button>
```